# What to do about "set -o vi" breaking X on raspbian

Tags: login, lightdm

I use KornShell almost exclusively, and I use the following in my .profile for all systems that I log in to:

```
set -o vi
```

Recently, I began using the desktop for Raspberry Pi (all these years, I've been using only SSH access for all my many Pi devices.  I found that, after I installed some basic software (ksh, php, a few others) and copied my standard .profile onto a fresh system, I could no longer log into the windows system... it would accept my password, blank the screen, and return to login (!!!!!).  No logs or error messages I could find resulted from this problem, it just silently refused to log me in.  Or it logged me in, did nothing and then waited for me to log in again - who's to say?

It took me a LONG time (and literally days of searching, off and on, for help with things like "raspbian blank display and return to login" and on and on...).  Only today I identified that my problem was with .profile, so commented all lines of my .profile and then painstakingly went through this process to identify the problem:

```
One line or section at a time:
    uncomment only one line or section of .profile
    Reboot
    Observe whether can log in, modify .profile accordingly for next test
```

After going through this process for my entire .profile, it turned out that only the lines that had "set -o vi" or "set -o vi-tab-complete" would cause this phenomena.  (Lest I confuse you, the actual code looks like the following.)

```
set -o vi
set -o vi-tabcomplete 2>/dev/null # Some systems need this, some don't support it
```

I love the way 'set -o vi' (or with tab-complete) works with KornShell, and it has become a part of my daily life for so many years, so I want to keep it.  But I only need it on a terminal, and I avoid xterm and so on. (Call me a relic, I don't mind.)

How can I change my .profile so that it doesn't impact the desktop display while maintaining that set -o functionality that I use on so many other systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a great question!

***Confession:*** This answer is *theory*, not practice. I've never used the korn shell, and I've never logged into a RPi with an attached monitor.

Anyway, it seems to me that your problem *may be* solved by **not** running the `set -o ...` commands in your `.profile` except when you are logged in over SSH. Perhaps add something like this to your `.profile` ? :

```sh
if [ -n "$SSH_CLIENT" ] || [ -n "$SSH_TTY" ]; then
    set -o vi 
fi
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you so much; all these years I hadn't recognized there were shell variables set specific to SSH sessions.  My life is changed!  :)  I appreciate the simple and workable reply, @Seamus!

Comment: @Dennis: And thank you - that's the best reception I've ever gotten for an answer :)